# How do I pass the "isVisibility" value as a prop to another component (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass the isVisibile value to the component "Livechat.js" so that I can dynamically edit some info there according to the value of isVisibile.

File where the isVisibile logic is - NewsLetter.js

```
const NewsLetter = () => {

const newsLetterRef = useRef();
const [isVisible , setIsVisible] = useState()
useEffect( () => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver( (entries) => {
        const entry = entries[0];
        setIsVisible(entry.isIntersecting)
    })
    observer.observe(newsLetterRef.current)
} , [])

  return (
    <>
        <NewsLetterWrapper>
            <div ref={newsLetterRef} className={styles.newsLetterCenter}>
                <div className={styles.newsLetterContainer}>
                    <div>
                      <p className={styles.newsLetterTitle}>Subscribe To Our <br /> <span> Newsletter For 10% - 50% OFF </span>   </p>    
                      <p className={styles.newsLetterDesc}>Stay up to date with our latest offers and  promotions by signing up now! <br /> Be the first to know of our 10% - 50% discounts.</p>                    
                    </div>

                    <div className={styles.newsLetterInputContent}> 
                    <div>
                        <input className={styles.newsLetterInput} type="text" placeholder='Enter email' />
                    </div>
                        <PrimaryButton>
                            Submit
                        </PrimaryButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </NewsLetterWrapper>
    </>
  )
}

export default NewsLetter
```

Where I want to use the prop - Live.js

```
const Livechat = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
        <div className={styles.whatsappFloat}>
            <div className={styles.chatText}>
                <p>Chat With Us Now</p>
            </div>
            <a href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=000000000' >
                <img src={LivechatImg} alt= "/" />
            </a>    
        </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Where I use both components on one page - Homepage.js

```
const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <>
     <Livechat />
     <NewsLetter /> 
    </>
```

What I want to do is basically get the isVisibile Value from NewsLetter and pass it as a prop to Livechat component. Any idea how i am supposed to achieve this ? Any help would be appreciated , Thank you in advance.

Comment: A good way to achieve this is to lift the state up from Newsletter to Homepage then pass the state as prop to both components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend moving `isVisible` into HomePage which would allow you to pass it to both components. You can then update `isVisible` by passing a function `onIsVisibleChange()`.

```js
const HomePage = () => {

  const [isVisible , setIsVisible] = useState()

  return (
    <>
     <Livechat onIsVisibleChange={setIsVisible}/>
     <NewsLetter isVisible={isVisible}/> 
    </>
}
```

You can update it in NewsLetter:

```js
const NewsLetter = (props) => {

  const {onIsVisibleChange} = props;

  const newsLetterRef = useRef();

  useEffect( () => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver( (entries) => {
        const entry = entries[0];
        onIsVisibleChange(entry.isIntersecting);
    })
    observer.observe(newsLetterRef.current)
  } , [])

  ...

}
```

Similarly, in Livechat you can use the variable like this:

```
const Livechat = (props) => {

  const {isVisible} = props;

  return (
    <>
        <div className={styles.whatsappFloat}>
            {isVisible && 
              <div className={styles.chatText}>
                <p>Chat With Us Now</p>
              </div>
            }
            <a href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=000000000' >
                <img src={LivechatImg} alt= "/" />
            </a>    
        </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: I got this error in console - onIsVisibleChange is not a function. Which was on this line.  onIsVisibleChange(entry.isIntersecting);

Comment: Must be something wrong in your code, [here is a simplified example](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-leaf-dbeip6?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: It said it cannot find the sandbox

Comment: try again https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-leaf-dbeip6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Found the problem. I rather put <Livechat isVisible={isVisible}/> and <NewsLetter onIsVisibleChange={setIsVisible} /> Just noticed these two had to be switched. Thanks by the way :)

Comment: I will edit the answer now